# Unwanted Blank screen showing on app start up android jetpack compose - android studio chipmunk.-How to remove it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-splashscreen

I just created an empty project and run it on device. On the app start up it shows a default blank screen on start up(app launch) before the first activity. I went through many answers and didn't find an exact answer or the root cause from where it is showing up. Many answers told to add

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

in themes.xml. Even after adding I still see the blank screen appearing.
Also in some other answer they told about new splash screen api, but I didn't feel it much customizable for doing server calls and other operations in splash screens. Also its available in below 12 versions.
What is right solution to handle this unwanted glitches during app startup?
Your help is highly appreciated.

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Owl" parent="@style/Theme.Material.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff00ff</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff00ff</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/immersive_sys_ui</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/nav_bar</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Material.DayNight.NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />

</resources>
```

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Comment: You can change the color adding `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/your_color</item>` in your theme. For Android 12 or higher you can use `<item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/...</item>`

Comment: Actually i want to get rid of that default screen and need to implement different ui containing gif image in splash screen . Is that possible?

Comment: Then the best option is the splash screen api

Comment: How can we add .gif image which is in drawable in splash screen using this splash screen api?

Comment: The blank screen mostly is caused by initial load in your app.

Comment: I created an empty compose project and run it. The same issue occurs @BincyBaby

Comment: try setting the theme of your splash screen activity to Theme.NoDisplay

Comment: @Nadeem where does that Theme.NoDisplay come from is that default

Comment: Have you made any changes to the empty project? Black screen with the logo? Which studio version are you using? What device are you running the app on? @HarishPadmanabh

Comment: @Harish Padmanabha <style name="Theme.Mytheme" parent="android:Theme.NoDisplay" />